# change.after.val() returns full JSON object rather than value of the object

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a Firebase Cloud Function. When I log the value of change.after.val() I get a printout of a key-value pair

```
{ DCBPUTBPT5haNaMvMZRNEpOAWXf3: 'https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=t-7mQhSZRgM' }
```

rather than simply the value (the URL). Here's my code. What am I not understanding about .val() ? Shouldn't "updated" simply contain the URL?

```
exports.fanOutLink = functions.database.ref('/userLink').onWrite((change, context) => {

const updated = change.after.val();
console.log(updated);

return null

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only the URL value, you should include a wildcard in your trigger path for the URL key:

```
exports.fanOutLink = functions.database.ref('/userLink/{keyId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  console.log('keyId=', context.params.keyId);

  const updated = change.after.val();
  console.log(updated);

  return null
});
```

In the Realtime Database, data is [modeled as a JSON tree](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore?authuser=0#data_model). The path specified in an event trigger identifies a node in the tree.  The value of the node, being JSON, includes all child nodes.  The change parameter for the trigger event refers to the value of the entire node.

I indicated above that you can change the trigger path to refer one level down.  An alternative is to access the children of the node using the [child()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot?authuser=0#child) method of `DataSnapshot`.

Without knowing your use-case, it's hard to be more specific about the trigger event path you should use.  Keep in mind that the event fires when any element of the node value changes, whether it be a simple value at the root level, or a value of a child node.  It is often the case that you want the trigger to be as specific as possible, to better identify what changed.  That's where wildcards in the path are useful.  As I showed in the code I posted, the string value of a wildcard is available from the `context` parameter.

Comment: Thanks very much. I vaguely understand why this would be the case, but can you clarify a bit why?

Comment: @luciusdegeer: I updated my answer to provide more explanation.

Comment: How can I access the values of the object in change.after.val() ??? If I do cont valueOfKey = change.after.val().status I get an error.